# Fabs With Labels In Ionic 3

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view, ionic-native

I am using the Ionic 3 Framework and want to insert the following type of fab menu in my Ionic 3 App.

Special Fab Menu:

[image]

Comment: Not enough context.  Are these Fab icons ones that you already have and have been able to include.

Answer (score 7):

In your SCSS file:

```
button[ion-fab] {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;

    ion-label {
        position: absolute;
        top: -8px;
        right: 40px;

        color: white;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        line-height: 24px;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
}

.fab{
    contain: layout;
}
```

Your HTML file:

```
<ion-fab bottom right >
  <button ion-fab>Share</button>
  <ion-fab-list side="top">
     <button ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Facebook</ion-label>
     </button>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

Please refer to this link...

[whats the correct way of inserting label in an Ionic FAB list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842324/whats-the-correct-way-of-inserting-label-in-an-ionic-fab-list)

This one is fairly easy to impelement. I've tested this on Ionic 3 and it works

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @mark. for right to left languages **(rtl)** you should alter the scss file according to this: (add **left: 45px;** instead of  right: 40px;)

```
button[ion-fab] {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;

    ion-label {
        position: absolute;
        top: -8px;

        // this is the difference: 
        left: 45px;

        color: white;
        background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.7);
        line-height: 24px;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 12px
    }
}

.fab{
    contain: layout;
}
```

I also changed the background color of ion-label and its font size to appear more beautiful.

And your html file should be like the @mark:

```
   <ion-fab bottom right >
      <button ion-fab>Share</button>
      <ion-fab-list side="top">
         <button ion-fab>
            <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Facebook</ion-label>
         </button>
      </ion-fab-list>
    </ion-fab>
```