# Ionic 3 How to add a non-wrapping label to a fab

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3, floating-action-button

I have a fab list with fab buttons that shall have labels.

I found [Fabs With Labels In Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932699/fabs-with-labels-in-ionic-3) & [whats the correct way of inserting label in an Ionic FAB list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842324/whats-the-correct-way-of-inserting-label-in-an-ionic-fab-list).

My HTML code is:

```
<ion-fab left top>
    <button ion-fab color="light">
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-fab-list side="bottom">

      <button ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Test Test Test</ion-label>
      </button>


      <button ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="alarm"></ion-icon>
        <ion-label>Bla Bla</ion-label>
      </button>

    </ion-fab-list>

  </ion-fab>
```

CSS

```
button[ion-fab] {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;

  ion-label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;

    top: -8px;
    left: 60px;

    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    line-height: 24px;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;


    pointer-events: auto;
  }

  contain: layout;
}
```

But the labels break the text to a newline if i don't specify a width.
If i do the labels don't adjust their width to the label's content.

[image]

How do i make the label content not wrap to a new line?

Comment: refer this link https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/fab-labels-in-ionic-4/139823/14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue originated from

```
ion-label {
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

from my app.scss

Answer (score 0):

I have create a demo in ionic 3. You can check it:

Try this:

[Stackblitz - Ionic 3 Fab button Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-a9l5bf)

Comment: @Chandrankant Devani That's exactly what i did. Doesn't work. i'll compare the computed styles.