# In "ion-fab-list" element, some buttons show up and others don't

Tags: ionic3

I have some buttons in the ion-fab-list element. Only one of the buttons namely "mail" shows up. Other buttons do not show up. How can this be fixed?

```
<ion-fab right bottom>
  <button ion-fab color="accent"><ion-icon name="arrow-dropup"></ion-icon></button>
  <ion-fab-list side="top">
    <button ion-fab class="btn-google-plus"><ion-icon name="logo-googleplus"></ion-icon></button>
    <button ion-fab class="btn-mail"><ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon></button>

    <button ion-fab class="btn-youtube"><ion-icon name="logo-youtube"></ion-icon></button>
    <button ion-fab class="btn-twitter"><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></button>
    <button ion-fab class="btn-facebook"><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></button>
    <button ion-fab class="btn-linkedin"><ion-icon name="logo-linkedin"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

This is a screenshot of the same.
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FToPN.jpg)
As a side note, I am using ionic v3.9.2, node v8.11.3

Comment: <button ion-fab class="btn-mail"><ion-icon name="mail"></ion-icon></button>
 Only this is appearing... if you copy it many times instead of others will it show all or just 1?

Comment: @MostafaHarb it shows as many times as I type the "mail" button.

Comment: Now use any other one than mail and give he button ion-fab the class of mail(btn-mail) and try to see if it shows or not

Comment: It starts to show up if I add class of mail to other buttons. Why does this happen?

Comment: The problem is in the other classes,only the mail have correct class info to be shown as a fab, while others my not be apropriate for being as fab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Mostafa in comments, the class for icons other than mail might not be configured. Current version of [ion-fab doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/fab-button) doesn't explicitly endorse use of class attribute. Some links to configure class for ion-fab are [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842324/whats-the-correct-way-of-inserting-label-in-an-ionic-fab-list) and [link2](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/fab-labels-in-ionic-4/139823/7)

As for showing other icons, giving them class mail fixes the issue.